# 16 responsive divs that fill the entire page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to fill an entire page with 16 divs but still have it responsive so it can be viewed on different devices. At the moment I have only used percentages but I am open to other solutions if there are any.

-How it is suppose to look.

The webpage has to contain 16 divs in total four spread across the top first quater of the webpage four spread across the second quarter of the page four spread across the third quarter of the page and four spread across the forth quarter of the page.

So overall it is suppose to look like a big cube or look like the 2408 game http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/

-My code so far

```
***HTML***

<!doctype html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
</head>


<!-- ========================================================================================================================= -->
<div id="s1" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s2" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s3" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s4" class="divq"> </div>
<!-- ========================================================================================================================= -->
<div id="s5" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s6" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s7" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s8" class="divq"> </div>
<!-- ========================================================================================================================= -->
<div id="s9" class="divq"> </div>       <div id="s10" class="divq"> </div>      <div id="s11" class="divq"> </div>      <div id="s12" class="divq"> </div>
<!-- ========================================================================================================================= -->
<div id="s13" class="divq"> </div>      <div id="s14" class="divq"> </div>      <div id="s15" class="divq"> </div>      <div id="s16" class="divq"> </div>
<!-- ========================================================================================================================= -->


***CSS***

html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

.divq {
height: 25%;
margin: 0px;
width: 25%;
}

#s1 {
background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
float: left;
}
#s2 {
background-color: rgb(120,100,100);
}
#s3 {
background-color: rgb(100,120,100);
}
#s4 {
background-color: rgb(100,100,120);
float: right;
}
#s5 {
background-color: rgb(140,100,100);
float: left;
}
#s6 {
background-color: rgb(100,140,100);
}
#s7 {
background-color: rgb(100,100,140);
}
#s8 {
background-color: rgb(160,100,100);
float: right;
}
#s9 {
background-color: rgb(100,160,100);
float: left;
}
#s10 {
background-color: rgb(100,100,160);
}
#s11 {
background-color: rgb(180,100,100);
}
#s12 {
background-color: rgb(100,180,100);
float: right;
}
#s13 {
background-color: rgb(100,100,180);
float: left;
}
#s14 {
background-color: rgb(200,100,100);
}
#s15 {
background-color: rgb(100,200,100);
}
#s16 {
background-color: rgb(100,100,200);
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Are you ok with using flexbox?

Comment: So the question is 'Is it possible'? Yes, look at flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them all `float: left`, and don't forget to add `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements (via `.divq`)

That way you can add margings and paddings without breakting your grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with flexbox, you can span four rows inside a wrapper with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`, each including four columns.

Sample Fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/n50tnnka/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with **Flexbox** like this

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/384/)**

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  flex: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)? It's fairly easy to use!

Just give your div's the `class` col-md-3. That way, the div's will know they can take up 3/12th of the screen = 25% = 4 divs per row.
If you then contain all these divs in one parent div with fixed width and height, you should be fine.

```
<div id="cube">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s7"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s8"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s11"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s12"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s13"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s14"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s15"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="s16"></div>
</div>
```

By still using the id's you can give any square the color you like, but by using bootstrap you [won't have to use float](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/css-float-width-issues-27688.html).

Answer (score 0):

For better browser support (than flex) you can use display table-cell for your elements
But you will have to nest each "row" (four divs) in a parent element:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="s1" class="divq"> </div>
  <div id="s2" class="divq"></div>
  <div id="s3" class="divq"> </div>
  <div id="s4" class="divq"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.row{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
}
.divq {
  display:table-cell;
  height: 25%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/06z1L5tg/